# Devexpress:aspxtextbox text validation

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to enable another textbox depends on the the text of the first textbox. But I don't know the syntax in devexpress:aspx.

```
dx:ASPxLabel ID="ASPxLabel1" runat="server" Text="ID">
   </dx:ASPxLabel>
       <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="textbox_ID" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="83px" 
                ClientInstanceName="textbox_ID" AutoPostBack="false">
           <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s,e){

           if(textbox_ID.GetText()==ABC){
             alert(textbox_ID.GetText());
             textbox_Name.SetEnabled(true);
           }
           else{
             textbox_Name.SetEnabled(false);
           }
           }" />
      </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

I think the problem is the "if condition".
What is the solution for my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have missed single quotes in this line:

```
if(textbox_ID.GetText()==ABC){
```

so change it to:

```
if(textbox_ID.GetText()=='ABC'){
```

the rest of validation method looks good.

Comment: Thank you Andrews for your solution. It works and now my problem is  fixed.

Comment: @TimothyVarian welcome to StackOverflow! If this answer (and any other answer in the future) has helped you make sure you mark it as the accepted answer by checking the check-mark to the left under the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you set **ABC** then JavaScript consider that as page element or variable. Since it is string you have enclosed with single quote **'ABC'**.